# Swift BLE communication between iPhone and ESP32

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am a complete noobie in Swift and have therefore some very basic questions.
I planned to build a simple iPhone app, which can talk (bidirectional) with my ESP32 which is connected to my eBike controller. The ESP32 is set up to transmit and receive data over BLE. It sends 4 signals: mode(1,2,3), light(on/off), bat(battery; values between 31,5 and 41,5) and speed(float) and accepts to commands: "um" to change the mode and "li" to switch between light on/off

The respective UUIDs are as followed

```
#define SERVICE_UUID           "19074fb4-161b-47c7-964e-9d087266d6a7" 
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX "101880eb-a78e-4cee-b252-56e06093f4da"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_MODE "5d64d30b-3e03-4e65-82a2-a85e9d568f84"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_LIGHT "dfbec318-8292-4b34-87b5-f13e4efb1560"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_BAT "a5b79c5d-977a-4ef0-b3f3-b8f26e166378"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_SPEED "b0bfad34-c571-41a5-8bc3-7726ced1ebbe"
```

on the Swift side, I have the UI, but I can't the get the buttons (mode, light, connect) and the connection to work properly.

Here is my **swift file** incl. the BLE-functions:

```
//
//  BLEController.swift
//  Bike Controller
//
//  Created by David Melinc on 19.05.22.
//

import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

struct Peripheral: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let rssi: Int
}

class BLEController: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
   
    var myCentral: CBCentralManager!
    var myPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
   
    @Published var isSwitchedOn = false
    @Published var peripherals = [Peripheral]()
    @Published var mode: UInt16 = 0
    @Published var light: String = " "
    @Published var bat: UInt16 = 0
    @Published var speed: UInt16 = 0
    
    let SERVICE_UUID  = CBUUID(string: "19074fb4-161b-47c7-964e-9d087266d6a7")
    let CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX  = CBUUID(string: "101880eb-a78e-4cee-b252-56e06093f4da")
    let CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_MODE  = CBUUID(string: "5d64d30b-3e03-4e65-82a2-a85e9d568f84")
    let CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_LIGHT  = CBUUID(string: "dfbec318-8292-4b34-87b5-f13e4efb1560")
    let CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_BAT = CBUUID(string:  "a5b79c5d-977a-4ef0-b3f3-b8f26e166378")
    let CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_SPEED  = CBUUID(string: "b0bfad34-c571-41a5-8bc3-7726ced1ebbe")

    override init() {
        super.init()
        myCentral = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
   
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            isSwitchedOn = true
        }
        else {
            isSwitchedOn = false
        }
    }    
    
       func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        var peripheralName: String!
           
        if let name = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
            peripheralName = name
        }
        else {
            peripheralName = "Unknown"
        }
           
        let newPeripheral = Peripheral(id: peripherals.count, name: peripheralName, rssi: RSSI.intValue)
        print(newPeripheral)
        peripherals.append(newPeripheral)
        
    }

     
    func connectBLE(peripheral1) {
        print("trying to connect to \(peripheral1)")
                        self.myCentral.connect(peripheral1, options: nil)
                        print(2)
                        }
            }
        }
         
    }

    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.myPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        print("Connected to "+peripheral.name!)
    }
    
    func startScanning() {
        print("startScanning")
        myCentral.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        self.perform(#selector(stopScanning), with: self, afterDelay: 5)
    }
    @objc func stopScanning() {
        print("stopScanning")
        myCentral.stopScan()
    }
}
```

**Here is the UI file:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct BLEdevices: View {
    
    //@StateObject var bleController = BLEController()
    @EnvironmentObject var bleController: BLEController
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("Themecolor")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack (spacing: 10) {
                    Text("Bluetooth Devices")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    List(bleController.peripherals) { peripheral in
                        HStack {
                            Text(peripheral.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(String(peripheral.rssi))
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                //bleController.connectBLE(peripheral.name)
                                    }) {
                                Text("CONNECT")
                                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .padding()
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .frame(alignment: .center)
                                    .background(
                                      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                          .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                          .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(10)))
                                    }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 600)
                    HStack (spacing: 10) {
                        Button(action: {
                            bleController.startScanning()
                                }) {
                            Text("SCAN")
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .center)
                                .background(
                                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                      .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                      .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(25)))
                                }
                        Button(action: {
                            bleController.stopScanning()
                                }) {
                            Text("STOP")
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .center)
                                .background(
                                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                      .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                      .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(25)))
                                }
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
}

struct BLEdevices_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BLEdevices()
    }
}
```

I would like to run the connectBLE function after I scanned the surrounding.

my questions are therefore as follows,

1.) how can I connect to a specific device after I scanned the whole area?
I have problems to get from the "peripheral.name" back to the CBPeripheral format, which I could use to put in my myCentral.connect function.
2.) how can I receive and transmit data between the two devices after they are connected?
All signals from ESP32 are transmitted via notify from the ESP32 using separate UUIDs, but I don't know how I get/handle them on the Swift side.
With the buttons "mode" and "light" I want to send simple ASCII code to the ESP32.

I would highly appreciate, if someone can help me here as I am stuck.

Best David

[image: UI of main page]

Comment: Don't scan for services `nil`; you know the service you want. Scan for peripherals advertising that service. The name is unreliable. Once you identify the peripheral you want, you can store its `identifier` to identify it in the future. Once you get the `didConnect` callback you will need to call `discoverServices` to actually get the service you are interested in and then call `discoverCharacteristics` to get the characteristics. Then you can read and write values to the characteristics

Comment: you are right, I can make a connection, but I want It to be universal, so that it first looks for everything and THEN connects to a particular one that I choose

Comment: can you show me an example code for the discoveredServices, discoverCharacteristics and and read and write example? (as said Im pretty new and have troubles figuring it out by myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is important that you advertise the service to be found, not only create/facilitate. Apps like nRF connect can help you determine if the service is advertised, otherwise the scan for services (that particular service) will be unsuccessful.

And for the second question: watch his work https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor

You can read out characteristics intended to be read and vice versa to write. Notification is not always needed.

Comment: Hello, are we talking about the advertisement of the iPhone or the ESP?
I Stumbled across his tutorial, but could not make it work. Especially I haven't found any indication how to send the ASCII from the phone to the ESP.

Comment: Advertisement of the one which serves the services: the ESP. 

Try the nRF Connect app and try to connect to your esp by bluetooth. Therefore the ESP should be discoverable, thus not connected to another device. 

In that app, click your device and press client in the upper menu. If advertised services is empty, it is an advertisement problem. If you press connect, you should see the services and characteristics which are available.

Comment: NB: you use a 128 uuid, so the name of the device should be small, otherwise advertisement is unsuccessful:
"...The maximum Advertising Data length for undirected connectable advertising is BLE_ADV_DATA_LEN_MAX bytes (31 minus 3 that are reserved to set the Advertising Data type flags - which shall not be set in Advertising Data using this function)...

Comment: Thanks for that! I forgot to mention, that the esp side seems to work (I can connect it to several other apps and read and write as I want it to be). I just want to build my own app to do that in a more dedicated way (nicer UI)

Comment: I am in the same process! Awaiting approval of Apple. If you stumble at the advertisement, i can post code.

Comment: I want to use the app just for my personal usage. Do you know how to send data from the phone to the peripheral using the characteristics?

Comment: You need something like this: https://github.com/Mair/esp32-course/tree/master/_19_bluetooth_BLE/_19_5_GATT_Battery_Read The sky is the limit: you can use strings, structs, bytes etc. If you are on a data budget, consider using structs of bytes/uint8 and you could even use every byte on a bit level to toggle 8 variables every time. (like with a bit mask) If this solves your questions, consider closing this topic.